# Search a Substring in a List<string>

Tags: wpf, lambda

I have a List of Codes (COD_XX) and I need to search each code in a text file, and get the index of the line where is located. The first caracter of the line contains the cod.
I've saved all the lines in a List

```
        var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
        List<string> fileItems = new List<string>(fileLines);

        foreach (string param in lstCodes)
        {
           int idx = fileItems.FindIndex(m => m.Substring(0,6) == param)
        }
```

But this expression is not working :( How should I writte it?
Thank you in advanced for your help.

Comment: Your code works fine if you put `;` after `fileItems.FindIndex(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine if you put `;` after `fileItems.FindIndex(...)`

But `m.Substring(0,6)` could throw an exception if m is shorter than 6. 
You should use `String.StartsWith` method.

```
foreach (string param in lstCodes)
{
   int idx = fileItems.FindIndex(m => m.StartsWith(param));
}
```